# Angular 2.0 - What's the difference between @ViewQuery and @Query

Tags: typescript, angular

From what I've read in the [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/QueryList-class.html) of `QueryList`, `@Query` should allow for the ability to inject a reference to a child component into a given component.

Using `@QueryView` I've managed to get a reference to a child DOM element like so:

```
// Parent component's template
<my-component #test>

// Parent component
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(@Query('test') child: QueryList<any>) {...}
}
```

I expected that `@Query` may return the matching component rather than the DOM element, but I haven't managed to get it working, nor have I found any documentation that indicates so.

What's the difference between these two decorators?

Comment: `@ViewQuery` queries the View DOM (the view you specify in a template, aka Shadow DOM), and `@Query` queries for the light DOM when you use it in a Directive (see this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1935)). Keep in mind that in the next release, alpha38, both ViewQuery and Query will be renamed (See [#3922](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3922)).

Comment: Eric, what do you mean by 'light DOM'? Is there any way to get a reference to child components, such that you could then call its methods? Thanks for the warning regarding alpha38!

Comment: I got 'light DOM' from here [About shadow DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/shadow-dom.html). Here's an example of how to do it : [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGupqC?p=preview), see the comment in it.

Comment: I can't edit my last comment. Well, regarding the comment in the plnkr, see [this](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=55f6d1118cc5f90a4fb6c4ad) from there to a little below (@jamesmoey's comments).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you must understand what are the Light DOM and Shadow DOM. These terminologies have come from web components. So [here is the link](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/). In general:

- ***Light DOM*** - is the DOM that **the end-user of your component** supply into your component.
- ***Shadow DOM*** - is the internal DOM of your component that is defined **by you** (as a **creator of the component**) and hidden from the end-user.

I think, looking at the next example you can easily understand what is what ([here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLbED3ITBrJqpPOtXgqj?p=preview)):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <h1>I am Shadow DOM!</h1>
    <h2>Nice to meet you :)</h2>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `;
})
class SomeComponent { /* ... */ }

@Component({
  selector: 'another-component'
})
@View({
  directives: [SomeComponent],
  template: `
    <some-component>
      <h1>Hi! I am Light DOM!</h1>
      <h2>So happy to see you!</h2>
    </some-component>
  `
})
class AnotherComponent { /* ... */ }
```

So, the answer for you question is pretty simple:

> The difference between `Query` and `ViewQuery` is that `Query` is looking for elements in Light DOM while `ViewQuery` is looking for them in Shadow DOM.

**PS** The example shows simple content projection. But `<ng-content>` can do much more complex things. See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2529).

Comment: `@Query` and `@ViewQuery` are deprecated, use `@ContentChildren` and `@ViewChildren` instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you give us a link, to where they are marked as deprecated? Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.dart#L162, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata.dart#L137

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thank you. No mention in metadata.ts