# difference between ViewChildern and ContentChildern and how to use both practically?

Tags: angular

I'm probably confused with `ViewChildren` and `ContentChildren` and their practical usage.

Please tell me how to use them practically. what is their purpose?

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app', 
  template: `
 <h4>ParentCmp</h4>
 <button (click)="clicked()">show/hide</button>

 <child> first child from childcmp </child>
 <bR><bR>
 <child *ngIf="show"> second child from childcmp </child>
 <bR><bR>
 <child1></child1>
 `,
  directives: [childcmp,child1cmp],

})


export class ParentCmp {
  show:boolean=true;

  @ViewChildren(childcmp) viewChildren: QueryList<childcmp>;

  @ContentChildren(childcmp) contentChildren: QueryList<childcmp>;


  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log('viewChildren-> ' + this.viewChildren.length);
    console.log( 'contentChildren-> ' + this.contentChildren.length);
  }

  clicked()
  {
     this.show=!this.show;
     this.viewChildren.changes.subscribe(() =>  console.log('viewChildren-> ' + this.viewChildren.length));
     this.contentChildren.changes.subscribe(() => console.log('contentChildren-> ' + this.contentChildren.length));
 }

}

bootstrap(ParentCmp, []);
```

***child.ts***

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

  selector:'child',
  template:`

  <h5>child cmp</h5>
  <ng-content></ng-content>

  `
})

export class childcmp{
  msg()
  {
    console.log('msg from child');
  }
}
```

***child1.ts***

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

  selector:'child1',
  template:`

  <h5>child1 cmp</h5>
  <ng-content></ng-content>

  `      
})

export class child1cmp{
  msg()
  {
    console.log('msg from child1');
  }
}
```

questions related to this setup.

check my code here - http://plnkr.co/edit/F2pJn1zxGFdFYzpeEwe1?p=preview

1) `ParentComponent` has three children (`two child type` and `one child1 type`)

```
<child></child>
<child></child>
<child1></child1>
```

How can I get count 3 for three children?

2) What will be some logical/practical way to use `ViewChildren` and `ContentChildren` (its pretty confusing how and when to use them).

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681558/angular-2-0-whats-the-difference-between-viewquery-and-query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that "View" is the template of your component, while content is the HTML projected using `<ng-content>`.

Depending on where you want to access elements, you use `@ViewChildren()` (components template) vs `@ContentChildren()` (projected content)

`@ContentChildren()` in `ParentCmp` is redundant because it doesn't have an `<ng-content>` tag in it's template.

`Child` and `Child1` have an `<ng-content>` tag and there using `@ContentChilden()` could make sense.
If you use the child components in the template of parent like

```
<child>
  <child1><child1>
</child>
```

Then in `Child` you get the `Child1` element as `@ContentChildren()` result.

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5kJfvIjnC1ROKuXPKNKX?p=preview)

Comment: I have already seen dup of question and I have come up with my own plunker. May be you could suggest something with practical usage. I have done few things in plunker. You may extent your answer further.

Comment: absolutely brilliant Gunter. Thanks for making it clear to me about `ContentChilderen`. I  can see that you have made changes in `parentCmp`. And I totally understand your way of doing the things. But stillI wonder, my previous implementation of `<child></child><child></child<child1></child1>`, basically parent has 3 children. Is there a way to figure out 3 count for the same structure as they are (3) children of parentcmp?

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is about. I updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h8aT7cPuW2PCWBqUzlth?p=preview). If you have different component types, you can't query by type (only one type per query) but you still can query by template variable (`viewChildren2`). For template variables a list of names is supported though (`viewChildren3`)

Comment: Okay got it. I was having a bit wrong idea. You made it clear. Thanks a ton as always.